# Using Ant on Ubuntu 13.10 with OpenJDK

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant

So, I'm trying really hard to get Thinking In Java source code to work on Ubuntu 13.10 with OpenJDK, but I've run into a problem I've not been able to solve. So, I followed all the steps shown here:

http://www.mindviewinc.com/TIJ4/CodeInstructions.html

But when I try to compile everything using ant, when I type in the terminal `ant build` I get the following:

```
Buildfile: /home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/build.xml

build:

BUILD FAILED
/home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/build.xml:59: J2SE5 required
```

So first I reset my environment variables to make sure they were pointing at my JDK, by typing:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
$ export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Tried again, so luck. So I decided to check what the line causing the problem (59 in build.xml) which read `<fail message="J2SE5 required" unless="version1.5"/>`. Running `java -version` returns the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

So, I replaced the xml line with `<fail message="J2SE5 rEEEEquired" unless="version1.7.0_51"/>` and got the exact same thing after running `ant build`, except for the text I changed:

```
Buildfile: /home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/build.xml

build:

BUILD FAILED
/home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/build.xml:59: J2SE5 rEEEEquired
```

I tried with 1.7.0, 1.7, with no luck. I even tried deleting the line but I get this:

```
Buildfile: /home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/build.xml

build:

build:

BUILD FAILED
/home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/build.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/object/build.xml:29: J2SE5 required
```

So yeah. I really don't want to install Oracle's JDK because it seems too much of a hassle and I'm not even sure it would work. I'm fairly new to java and ant and even linux so this stuff really puzzles me. I can compile files alright and everything works as expected with the JDK, it's ant and that line that's giving me problems. Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! You also need to delete line 29 in:

```
/home/juan/Documents/TIJ4-code/object/build.xml
```

Comment: Well, there are like another 50 folders with a build.xml file each. When I delete the line at /object/build.xml it compiles everything in that folder and just jumps to the line in another folder's build.xml. I will try and delete every single one, I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @user2278662 Doh, sounds painful! At least on Linux this can be done as single line on the shell!